# Using BigQuery / Python3 / Reddit "Project name needs to be separated by dot" error

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, reddit

I have this code written in python3.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json

timeframe = '2006'

client = bigquery.Client()

query_job = client.query("SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.{}` LIMIT 05".format(timeframe))

results = query_job.result()
```

After setting the environment variable as it says to in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]
```

I get the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects
/ravischat-214114/queries/f936b73e-cf46-4fc5-b161-b05474c41560?maxResults=0: 
Project name needs to be separated by dot from dataset name, 
not by colon in table name "fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2006".
```

Any help for solving the error would be greatly appreciated!

If I need to set the path to the authentication JSON file directly in the code, if someone could tell me how to do that, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

According to the error displayed, change:

```
`fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2006`
```

to:

```
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2006`
```

Answer (score 0):

## BigQuery SQL : Standard dialects Vs Legacy Dialect

BigQuery uses two dialects of SQL, Legacy SQL and Standard SQL. By default dialect is set to Standard SQL. It can be changed using following line

Set use_legacy_sql to True to use legacy SQL syntax.

`job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=True)`

in that case `fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2006` is a valid and works.

If you are using standard SQL dialect, then it needs changed to`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2006` (replace colon with dot).